# opening several txt files using while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, text, while-loop

I have some txt files that their names have the following pattern:

```
arc.1.txt, arc.2.txt,...,arc.100.txt,..., arc.500.txt,...,arc.838.txt
```

I know  that we can write a program using `for loop` to open the files one by one, if we now the total numbers of files. I want to know is it possible to use `While loop` without counting the number files to open them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use a while loop assuming that the files are numbered in sequential order:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    filename = 'arc.%d.txt' % i
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file_handle:
            ...
    except IOError:
        break
```

Though this becomes pretty ugly with all the nesting.  You're probably better off getting the list of filenames using something like [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

```
from glob import glob
filenames = glob('arc.*.txt')
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as file_handle:
        ...
```

There are some race conditions associated with this second approach -- If the file somehow gets deleted between when `glob` found it and when it actually is time to process the file then your program could have a bad day.

Comment: thanks for your solution, would you please check my updated question ?

Answer (score 4):

```
import glob
for each_file in glob.glob("arc\.\d+\.txt"):
    print(each_file)
```

Comment: nit: Importing `os` doesn't seem necessary  and unless you're on python3.x only, I'd avoid using `file` as a variable name since it's the name of a builtin type on python2.x.

Comment: @StephenG, would you please check my updated question ?

Comment: Look at your glob and what I've updated mine to. Depends on the file names. The current glob i have match files with arc.[1 or more digits].txt

Answer (score 0):

If you add them all to a list and then remove them one by one and set the while condition to while (name of list) > 0: then open the next file